# ActiveMQ create hierarchical topics with wildcards

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, wildcard, hierarchical

I have read in the ActiveMQ documentation, that subtopics can be created by using wildcards. So for instance I could create the topics:

- physicalEnvironmet.Conditions
- physicalEnvironmet.Infrastructure
- physicalEnvironmet.Location

I could then register to either one of the topics, or to all (physicalEnvironmet.>)

But how is it working for more complex structures, like this:

[image]

Would the topic for Flickering be called:

- physicalEnvironmet.Conditions.Light.Flickering

And could I still have a precise selection, like only subscribing to topics considered with light:

- physicalEnvironmet.Conditions.Light.>

So basically I am asking If there is a level restriction for subtopics and If there is maybe a more easy way to create hierarchical topic orders.

Comment: How many total topics do you anticipate?  What is the expected # of clients? What is the # of expected messages / hour? What is the expected message size in bytes?

Comment: The complete structure of topics is still undefined but If i had to guess Id say around 30-50.  For clients it is hard to say since the pub/sub is for self-adaptive systems so it could be quite a lot. (Easily over 100). Since sensors are involved it could be that messages are sent every few seconds. The size of messages is rather low because it will be JSON Objects  containing limited information.

Answer (score 2):

In my 10+ yrs of messaging, every hierarchal topic structure ends up being replaced, b/c the taxonomy never works out. Your overall message pattern suggests a moderate total volume, so I suggest a flexible event model where you use fields to define the variance vs topic names eventType="Environmental" sensorType="Light". This allows you to add new ones and then have the option of filtering out what clients want and do not want without having to mess with the broker.

Another option is to use JMS headers to do the same. This would allow you to use selectors to do broker-side filtering.